# Can I run Percona and MySQL concurrently, on the same server?

Tags: mysql, linux, percona

I have a slave server that is not heavily loaded.  I also have some mitigating circumstance that prevent me from being allowed to replace MySQL with Percona.

My dilemma is that Percona is a 'drop in replacement' for MySQL -- installing Percona 'takes over' the command 'mysql', for example.

After searching online for quite a while (perhaps using the wrong keywords), I have not been able to find a way to install or compile Percona & MySQL so that they both run on the same server (different ports, maybe?).

Is this possible?  Are there doc.s, links, etc. that I should read (RTM)?

Of note: this is on a Linux box (openSUSE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not going to use MySQL Sandbox, then please see this checklist for [installing multiple MySQL servers on a Linux box](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/manually-installing-multiple-mysql-instances-on-linux-howto).

In brief, the things you must separate are:

- The config file
- Port number
- Socket file
- Data directory
- Daemons

And of course, you can't just install both from package management software since they'll override one another. At least one has to be installed from binary (or else you need to do a lot of tweaking).

Answer (score 1):

I think if you have different installation directory, service name and port than there should be no problem running them together.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me why you want to run two servers on the same machine, but there are tools that help you set this up.  I'd suggest looking into [MySQL Sandbox](http://mysqlsandbox.net/) if this is what you want to do.  They run on different ports and have different data directories and configuration files.